# Access StringProperty data and use it (KIVY)

Tags: python, kivy

First of I wish to point out that that I have checked out many similar questions that end up using `StringProperty()` which only seems to work as expected when data from it is accessed after the on_release of a button or interaction with other UI widgets.

I am able to obtain the string property and set data successfully to it as follows in screen login

login.py

```
 self.parent.parent.parent.admin_widget.mylocation =  str(self.ulocation) #DAta from textinput
```

here my admin.py files looks as follows: I simply initiate the string property, now I have a method `get_users`, this method has a DataTable and it adds the widget to screen, the problem is when loaded initially the stringproperty is empty, it is later updated after the textinput submitted and i expect changing screen should invoke get_users to capture the current location value in stringproperty. How can I obtain this value mylocation and use it correctly to load data in the table the first time? Please help me out

```
class AdminWindow(BoxLayout):
data_items = ListProperty([])
mylocation = StringProperty()

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

    print(self.mylocation)

    content = self.ids.scrn_contents
    users = self.get_users()
    userstable = DataTable(table=users)
    content.add_widget(userstable)

def get_users_new(self):
    #Here is where I access the stringProperty value
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM products WHERE location =%s", (self.mylocation,))
    rows = mycursor.fetchall()
    arrows = str(mycursor.rowcount)
    self.ids.total_inventory.text = arrows + " Products"
    # create data_items
    for row in rows:
        for col in row:\
            self.data_items.append(col)
```

So how can create the UI datatable with location value initially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, first of all I had to take  all the content in the init (this is where the tables will be loaded) section and place it in a method. Therefore all I had to do was call this method from login.py window after a button click, hence by the time the user gets to admin page data has been loaded fresh.